# VBA for Publisher vs Word

Tags: vba, publisher

Trying to build a macro to copy data from Excel into MS Publsiher. I have the code for MS Word but it does not seem to work when applied to Publisher. It fails at this line appPub.ActiveWindow.Bookmarks("Growth").Paste

**Word VBA:**

```
    Sub SendData()
    Dim WordApp As Object
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ' Sheet1 is the codename for the sheet with the named range you want to copy,
    ' this is the name of the sheet in brackets in the VBAProject explorer, not the
    ' friendly name given on the worksheet tab itself visible to the end user.
    Set ws = Sheet4
    ' This is the constant string which holds the filepath to your Word document
    Const WORDDOC As String = "C:\Quarterly Reports - Word Version\Growth.docx"

    WordApp.Visible = True

    WordApp.Documents.Open WORDDOC

    ' Copies the named range "OrderRange" from the Excel book 
        'you are running this from.
    ws.Range("Growth").Copy
    ' Pastes it to the bookmark "OrderBookmark" in your Word doc template.
    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Growth").Range.PasteAppendTable
    ' Sets your printer in Word to Adobe PDF and then prints the whole doc.
    ' WordApp.ActivePrinter = "Adobe PDF"
    ' WordApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    End Sub
```

**Publisher VBA:**

```
    Sub SendDataPB()
    Dim appPub As Object
    Set appPub = CreateObject("Publisher.Application")
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    ' Sheet1 is the codename for the sheet with the named range you want to copy,
    ' this is the name of the sheet in brackets in the VBAProject explorer, not the
    ' friendly name given on the worksheet tab itself visible to the end user.
    Set ws = Sheet4
    ' This is the constant string which holds the filepath to your Publisher document
    Const PublisherDOC As String = "C:\Quarterly Reports - Publisher     Version\Growth.pub"

    appPub.ActiveWindow.Visible = True

    appPub.Open PublisherDOC

    ' Copies the named range "OrderRange" from the Excel book
    '     you are running this from.
    ws.Range("Growth").Copy
    ' Pastes it to the bookmark "OrderBookmark" in your Publisher doc template.
    appPub.ActiveWindow.Bookmarks("Growth").Paste
    ' Sets your printer in Publisher to Adobe PDF and then prints the whole doc.
    ' PublisherApp.ActivePrinter = "Adobe PDF"
    ' PublisherApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut
    Set appPub = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Never worked with Publisher before but what I could understand is that the bookmarks in Publisher are not the same as Word Bookmarks. They are shapes of `.Type` as `pbWebHTMLFragment` and `.AutoShapeType` as `msoShapeMixed`. I believe you could however create a word template and then save it as a `.Pub` file?

Comment: Just checked in Publisher. The tooltip of `Bookmark` says `Bookmark appears as graphical elements on the page, and allow you to add hyperlinks to that location in the publication`

Comment: So do you think you would be able to write vba to point to the hyperlink? I can't do it in word and save as publisher because the template is specifically designed for publisher and gets distorted in word. I can't find much about vba into publisher...

Comment: How would that help? From what I could understand (and I could be wrong) but you cannot insert text at that book mark...

Answer (score 0):

ActiveWindow doesn't seem to contain any .Bookmarks collection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff939707.aspx

Try `ActiveDocument.Pages(YourPage).Shapes.Paste` perhaps... With some luck that pastes your copied table as a new shape. From then on you'd just need to think of a clever way to place and find placeholders, unless you manage to find a usable Bookmarks collection somewhere else in the object model... Good luck!